# Vue js, footer not displaying

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have installed vue cli, when i try to show my navbar(component) it shows but when i try to show my footer(component)it shows.
When i show other cms pages the navbar and footer are together the text is not displaying between...
Find the image, Output:
[image]
This is my navbar where it is a component under component folder

```
<template>
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/contacts" class="nav-link">Contacts Us</router-link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/login" class="nav-link">Login</router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      name: 'Navbar'
    }
</script>
```

This is my HomePage where it is a component under component folder

```
<template>
    <div>
        test
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'HomePage'
    }
</script>
```

This is App.vue Where it is inside the Src/ Folder

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
        <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'app-header': Navbar,
     'app-footer' : Footer
  }
}
</script>
```

This the Footer Component

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <footer class="text-muted">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="float-right">
          <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
        <p>Album example is © Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p>
        <p>New to Bootstrap? <a href="../../">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../../getting-started/">getting started guide</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Footer',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code for footer component?

Comment: check now i hv added

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: No, i didnt get any error, ill provide screen shot wait a sec

Comment: Are you sure the css is loading correctly?

Comment: yes even if i change my footer margin, the "test" String is coming below footer only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your App.vue template you have the order of the elements wrong.

Move the `<app-footer>` below rhe `<router-view>`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>

    <router-view></router-view>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template
```